# How to add a virtual monitor

Tags: display

I'm looking for a way to add a virtual monitor. I'm using EOS6

Virtual monitor as in a fake monitor that acts like a real one connected through HDMI/DP/USB. The aim is to run a full screen slideshow on it and present it to my class.

Comment: This can be done relatively easily, but the solution depends on your hardware. Do you have an Intel CPU with integrated graphics or an unused HDMI port available?

Comment: Yes, the machine's got an unused HDMI port. It's got Intel Skylake integrated graphics and also a Radeon GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have integrated graphics on an Intel chip, you can do this:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create an Xorg configuration file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Feel free to use any editor of your choosing. It does not need to be `vi`.</sup>
2. Paste the following into the new file:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier "intelgpu0"
       Driver "intel"
       Option "VirtualHeads" "1"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Reboot
4. Re-open Terminal and check the output of `xrandr`. So long as everything is as expected, you will see a line that says `VIRTUAL1 disconnected`
5. Confirm the name of your current output. It will look something like:

   ```
   HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
   ```
6. Use `cvt` to set a new `Modeline`:

   ```
   cvt 1920 1080
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Replace `1920` and `1080` with the resolution that you would like the virtual device to be.</sup>

   You should see some output that looks like:

   ```
   1920x1080 59.92 Hz (CVT 0.79M3) hsync: 47.82 kHz; pclk: 63.50 MHz
   Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"   63.50  1920 1072 1176 1328  1080 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
   ```
7. Set the new mode with the output from Step 6:

   ```
   $ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"   63.50  1920 1072 1176 1328  1080 771 775 798 -hsync +vsync
   $ xrandr --addmode VIRTUAL1 1920x1080_60.00
   ```
8. Set the virtual display as active:

   ```
   xrandr --output VIRTUAL1 --mode 1920x1080_60.00 --right-of HDMI1
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Change `HDMI1` to your actual display.</sup>

You should now have a virtual monitor positioned to the right of your active display. You can check this by looking at your display settings.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I tried it, tested my specific case and it worked. Thanks for the thorough guide.